# How to you import a class into the interactive window for pycharm or Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, pycharm

I am new to Python and I just began learning classes.  I wrote this very simple block of code.  It runs fine from the IDE but I can't seem to get it to run in the interactive console.  I've tried using the interactive console in Visual Studio and PyCharm.  The file is called **monster.py** in the project **New_Program.py**. In the interactive window I type **from monster import Monster**

In Visual Studio, I get the following error:
***Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named 'monster'***

In PyCharm, I don't get an error right away when I enter **from monster import Monster** But then when I try entering **mo.color** at the interactive prompt, I get the following error: **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Live\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "", line 1, in 
    mo.color
NameError: name 'mo' is not defined**

```
    class Monster(object):
        hit_points = 1
        color = "yellow"
        weapon = "sword"

    mo = Monster()
    mo.color
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only importing a specific name from monster.py into the namespace of your interpreter.

When you do the import, the code you've written does get executed, but `mo` is not available in your namespace and you therefore can't use it.

You could try one of the following:

1) Create the Monster instance in the terminal :

```
>>> from monster import Monster
>>> mo = Monster()
>>> mo.color
```

2) If you only need the instance, just import the instance :

```
>>> from monster import mo
>>> mo.color
```

3) Import the module into the namespace, not just the class :

```
>>> import monster
>>> monster.mo.color
```

4) (not really good practice) Import everything from the module into your namespace :

```
>>> from monster import *
>>> mo.color
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want to do is to initialise those parameters in the initiator.  Try

```
class Monster(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hit_points = 1
        self.color = "yellow"
        self.weapon = "sword"

mo = Monster()
print(mo.color)
```

Comment: I tried that I am am still getting an error in the interactive window.  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'mo' is not defined  Thanks for trying.

Comment: Are the two files in the same folder or different directories?

Comment: In PyCharms, the path is: C:\Users\Live\PycharmProjects\My First Project\monster.py  I tried typing in from C:\Users\Live\PycharmProjects\My First Project\monster.py import Monster and that didn't work  I get an invalid syntax error